# Scan and connect ios application to non Apple devices

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I am looking for the service provided by Apple to connect my iOS Application using bluetooth to a device. Yet, I can't even make it show to the list.

My device isn't BLE so I can't use CoreBluetooth and isn't an Apple product either, which make me unable to use ExternalAccessory.

Is there anything I am missing like a third framework or a library that could make the work ? I just need to connect my app to the bluetooth device then send and receive datas, nothing more.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you want to connect to an accessory from your iOS device using Classic Bluetooth, this accessory should participate in Apple MFi program, that includes adding a dedicated cryptographic chip to its logic board and signing an agreement with Apple. The documents for MFi developers are protected by NDA, so if you don't work for a vendor of an MFi-certified peripheral you shouldn't be able to connect to it directly.

While iOS can connect to Classic BT devices implementing some of standard BT profiles like PAN, MAP, HFP and such, this happens transparently from the application on the system level. For generic data transfer to/from a peripheral device you can only use `ExternalAccessory.framework` with MFi chip in Classic Bluetooth case or BLE.